# EXE files. How to run exe files in ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

im new to linux, so I wanted to ask, how to run exe files. Yeah yeah I seen wine. But its opening but, I cant do anything... I mean its like, broken. Idk how to say that, hope u help. (Ubuntu 20.4)

Comment: What software exactly?

Comment: Please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: You should try a front-end for wine.  I have posted an answer explaining a couple things for you.

Comment: This is a common question, easily and correctly answered by any Search Engine.

Comment: Wine does not work well with all software. We cannot answer this without knowing which software you intend to run. Many software have excellent free and open source alternatives.

Comment: I mean i trying to run software, from dvd, its some type of installer, its polish so it will be hard to understand....

Comment: Windows software is not meant to be run on Ubuntu.  You usually need something like Wine or use Windows OS in a virtual machine.  Quite a lot of software does have a good Linux alternative or might even have a Linux version.  Would check this out before trying to use Wine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXE Files can be run using a program called "WINE".  Remember though:
**W**ine
**I**s
**N**ot an
**E**mulator
It's a compatability layer.  Things may not work as expected.  You can also get front-ends to help you make your programs more stable, like PlayOnLinux, and Lutris.  I hope this helped you!

Comment: Thank you. You prop help me.

Comment: No problem!  Just a tip, read the links that the first comment on your post gave you.

Comment: Lutris work same as wine....

Comment: try play on linux.  If that doesn't work, try running winetricks and configuring wine a different way.

Comment: How to configure wine? PlayOnLinux dont work good too...

Comment: What program are you trying to run?